# Fast, vectorisable distance from points to ellipse

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, matlab

I am writing a program im Matlab to find ellipses in noisy XY data using a Random Sampling Consensus (RANSAC) algorithm. It basically samples enough points to define an ellipse and then determines the consensus as the number of points within a certain distance to this ellipse. After X trials, the ellipse with the most inliers is chosen.

Right now, I compute the distance of the points to the ellipse by generating 500 points on the ellipse boundary, compute the distance of every one of these ellipse points to the points to be fit, and select the least distance as the distance between the point and the ellipse. For the 1000 - 10000 points I want to fit to, this distance calculation is the bottleneck of the computation.

The algorithms I found for distance point to ellipse usually need to solve rather complex equations. Ideally, I am looking for an algorithm that can be vectorised, so the calculations can be done for every point I want to fit at the same time. If that isn't possible, fast methods that can be done in a loop for every point are also ok. Approximate solutions (maybe using an interpolation of the ellipse or something) are welcome.
 Thanks!

Comment: You can fit points to ellipses with (more or less regularized) linear least squares then to check the fit becomes a matrix-vector multiplication. Both the solving and the checking is therefore very straightforward to vectorize. There should exist plenty of articles for this. Maybe even good explanations on wikipedia and similar sites.

Comment: Do you propose to use least squares instead of RANSAC or within the Ransac loop? I chose Ransac because the data contains noise and (few) other structures than the ellipse.

Comment: @Lukas K. RANSAC is agnostic to method to do the actual fitting on points. It mostly considers how to decide which points to allow for fitting and which to exclude and how to update those lists based on previous fits.

Comment: @mathreadler So I take you propose I use least squares inside my ransac algorithm to rate the model defined by the sampled points. Could you please elaborate how I would do this? Especially considering that the ellipse model is an implicit equation? Thanks!